# load directive as template return blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the demo of the app :
http://plnkr.co/edit/rvS7YynFO9eIBavXf2IP?p=preview

I try to load friends' name into tab, but it doesn't appear. I've been debugging this for hours.

I've tried in index.html line 44

```
<friends tabFriends="tab.tabFriends"></friends>
```

and my friends.js seems no problem to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you casing for directive in HTML is not correct. This line

`<friends tabFriends="tab.tabFriends"></friends>`

should be

`<friends tab-friends="tab.tabFriends"></friends>`

See the [Matching Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) section in the directive guide.

Also in your friends.html template the expression should be

`{{friend.name}}`

Comment: is this a MUST? I'd used format without the '-' and it still worked.

Comment: If the variable name contains capital letter, then in the html you need to break with `-` instead of using capitals. See documentation.

Comment: and am I declare the scope right? like       scope: { tabFriends: '=tabFriends' }

Comment: what is the different with tabFriends : '=' and tabFriends : '=tabFriends' ??

Comment: If the name of the attribute is same as isolated scope variable name you can use the shorthand form `=`